# malformed JSON Retrofit2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

How to solve this error I get from the from android emulator

[image: error from android emulator]

> com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

```
private void registerToken(final String token) {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    tokenPostAPI = retrofit.create(TokenPostAPI.class);
    Call<String> tokenPostCall = tokenPostAPI.request(token);

    studentPostCall.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("token", "onFailure: "+t.toString() );
            Log.e("token", "onFailure: applied token "+token);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the applied token =

```
"fQEG8hgG8oE:APA91bGKsH78Ft6wCDW2EtMsuC19EXl10pxkJ95ZrVwnmaofFcw8-TgxeASujQva_gM7gYijIduYL82TmR5qeExxaeHP_252ZOSx7in99ShnaKwE8bsnOyYBDAI4M34d3APCiJKpWDqC "
```

Total token CHARACTERS 152.

Comment: The error means that what you try to parse is not correct JSON. Have a look at http://www.json.org/ for the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

**compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'**

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient() //building as lenient mode`enter code here`
        .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
```

Comment: Add this in your question section